# Is $\operatorname{Hom}(F,G)$ finite if $F$ and $G$ are endofunctors of the category of finite sets?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3217187/660) on Mathematics Stackexchange but got no answer.

Are there endofunctors $F$ and $G$ of the category of finite sets such that there are infinitely many natural transformations from $F$ to $G$?

Same question with $F$ and $G$ contravariant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you to Achim Krause for pointing out that the first version was broken. Let's try again.

Let $k$ be a finite field. For a set $X$, let $kX$ be the free vector space on $X$. Let $\bigwedge^{\bullet} kX$ be the exterior algebra on $kX$. Then $X \mapsto \bigwedge^{\bullet} kX$ becomes a functor in an obvious way.

Choose any scalars $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, ... in $k$ and define the natural transformation of $\bigwedge^{\bullet} kX$ by multiplying $\bigwedge^{j} kX$ by $a_j$. This gives infinitely (even uncountably) many natural transformations from $X \mapsto \bigwedge^{\bullet} kX$ to itself as a functor from finite sets to finite sets (or even from finite sets to vector spaces).

When studying functors $F$ from the category of finite sets or related categories, one usually wants to impose some sort of finite generation condition, saying roughly that there is some integer $N$ such that any subfunctor of $F$ which agrees with $F$ on sets of size $\leq N$ is the same as $F$. One does this precisely to avoid this sort of trickery with the functor $X \mapsto 2^X$. For example, [Eric Ramos, Graham White and I](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04238) classify functors from FI to FinSet with a finite generation hypothesis and my student [John Wiltshire-Gordon](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0786) classified functors from FinSet to $\mathbb{Q}$-Vect under a similar hypothesis. These are the two papers I know which come closest to studying functors from FinSet to FinSet.

Comment: Is $\phi_k$ really a natural transformation? Doesn't $\phi_k(f(S)) = f(\phi_k(S))$ fail if $S$ has size bigger than $k$ and $f(S)$ has size smaller than $k$?

Comment: You are right, I was trying to simplify too fast. See if this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1. In the contravariant case, does it suffice to replace $kX$ with its dual?

Comment: That assumption was made in the title of question.